# JSON query doesn't show items even if there is no errors when compiling

Tags: java, android, android-studio, youtube-api

I'm at very start of learning android, so now I have an aim to create an app using Youtube API with several functionalities, but one functionality like searching videos and list them on my screen - is not working and there are no errors, but when I press search button, nothing happen. Here is code for main class

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.app.youtubedownloader.Adapter.MyAdapter;
import com.app.youtubedownloader.Model.VideoDetails;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String API_KEY = "here is my api key";
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<VideoDetails> videoDetailsArrayList;
    MyAdapter myadapter;
    String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?";
    String part = "snippet";
    ImageButton searchbtn;
    EditText searchfield;
    String keySearch;
    Integer maxResults = 10;
    String order = "title";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listvideos);
        videoDetailsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        myadapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, videoDetailsArrayList);
        searchfield = findViewById(R.id.searchfield);
        searchbtn = findViewById(R.id.searchbtn);

        searchbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                keySearch =  searchfield.getText().toString();
                displayVideos();
            }
        });





    }

    public void displayVideos(){
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?" + "part=" + part + "&q=" + keySearch + "&maxResults=3" + "&order=" + order + "&key=" + API_KEY;

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

                    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject jsonVideoId = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("id");

                        JSONObject jsonObjectSnippet = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("snippet");

                        JSONObject jsonObjectDefault = jsonObjectSnippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("medium");

                        String video_id = jsonVideoId.getString("videoId");

                        VideoDetails vd = new VideoDetails();


                        vd.setVideoID(video_id);
                        vd.setTitle(jsonObjectSnippet.getString("title"));
                        vd.setDescription(jsonObjectSnippet.getString("description"));
                        vd.setUrl(jsonObjectDefault.getString("url"));

                        videoDetailsArrayList.add(vd);


                    }

                    listView.setAdapter(myadapter);
                    myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }

}
```

This is for adapter class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.app.youtubedownloader.Model.VideoDetails;
import com.app.youtubedownloader.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public Activity activity;
    public ArrayList<VideoDetails> videoDetailsArrayList;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<VideoDetails> videoDetailsArrayList){
    this.activity = activity;
    this.videoDetailsArrayList = videoDetailsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.videoDetailsArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return (long)position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if(inflater==null){
            inflater = this.activity.getLayoutInflater();
        }

        if( convertView==null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView imageView =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
        TextView textView =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleofitem);

        LinearLayout linearLayout =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.root);
        final VideoDetails videoDetails = this.videoDetailsArrayList.get(position);
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(activity, com.app.youtubedownloader.VideoPlay.class);
                i.putExtra("videoId",videoDetails.getVideoID());
                activity.startActivity(i);

            }
        });



        Picasso.get().load(videoDetails.getUrl()).into(imageView);
        textView.setText(videoDetails.getTitle());


        return  convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.videoDetailsArrayList.size();
    }

}
```

And this is for getters and setters

```
public class VideoDetails {
    public String videoID, title, description, url;

    public  VideoDetails(String videoID,String title,String description,String url){
        this.videoID = videoID;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.url = url;
    }
    public VideoDetails(){

    }

    public String getVideoID() {
        return videoID;
    }

    public void setVideoID(String videoID) {
        this.videoID = videoID;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

I think is not need for XML files. Thank you!
P.S. I tried to test my url request with postman, and it works.
edit:

```
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/zXtOj-qJByP8JvZOdTDcmmhSWNY\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAMQAA",
 "regionCode": "MD",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 3
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/XnyDQHIyLKnsfFTz76JxER0AjMg\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "aBABkTN8n_w"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-12-17T12:07:35.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCod_t2sXD_gRI11yFFGkoXg",
    "title": "Best Funny Videos 2018 ● Cute girls doing funny things P3",
    "description": "Hi my friends, please check our new compilation. Here is moments people funny videos and we hope that this video make your life more fun & you enjoy it ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aBABkTN8n_w/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aBABkTN8n_w/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aBABkTN8n_w/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Vines best fun",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/W8J9Seta9NO6dAqIWb5gcwfliPo\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "BgluGCjZKjM"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-06-20T17:26:22.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCeiZcfuj0r1ggNl0N_DVOgQ",
    "title": "Best FAILS &amp; Funny Videos ★ June 2017 Compilation ★ FailCity",
    "description": "Best fails and funny videos compilation of the June 2017! Every week there's new funny fails and awesome win fail video compilations! ＳＵＢＳＣＲＩＢＥ ғᴏʀ ᴍᴏʀᴇ ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BgluGCjZKjM/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BgluGCjZKjM/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BgluGCjZKjM/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Net Fail",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/sy1iQ191YnpipX54MZQ-Z-bd2YU\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#channel",
    "channelId": "UCUd0dDUCXsjBPnG1qeUHZLw"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2011-01-17T15:26:32.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCUd0dDUCXsjBPnG1qeUHZLw",
    "title": "funnyvideos",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-mULWh9j1SAI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/wtk972XjVNk/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-mULWh9j1SAI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/wtk972XjVNk/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-mULWh9j1SAI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/wtk972XjVNk/s800-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "funnyvideos",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "upcoming"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: If you have not already done so, you should put a breakpoint on the first instruction below the 'try' in the onResponse override, as well as the instruction in the 'catch' in the same override.  And, also on the first instruction in the onErrorResponse. Show us what string was returned in onResponse, or any Error messages returned. You should also show us the url after your string concatenation (obfuscate your api key).

Comment: What breakpoint do you mean I should add? And also, there is no error returned, that toast from Response.ErrorListener is not returned, because there is no error on response. And URL after concatenation is like this `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=Funnyvideos&order=title&maxResults=3&key=(key)`

Comment: In your onResponse override, you should highlight this line of code JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response); and select the Run menu, then Toggle Line Breakpoint.  This should put a red dot next to the line number on the far left (short cut, just tap to the right of the line number and the red dot will appear.  This will cause your code to pause during execution so you can display what came back in the response string, or, add an instruction Log.i("My App", "response:" + response); do the same in the catch e.printStackTrace(); or Log.e("My App", e.getLocalizedMessage();

Comment: When you run the app, make sure you click Run Debug (looks like a Ladybug) not Run (looks like a triangle) otherwise, your code will not stop on the breakpoints.

Comment: I edited question and added what I get in the response string, when searching funnyvideos

Comment: And this is what I get on e `org.json.JSONException: No value for videoId`

Comment: Is the JSONException message you are showing what is returned in the 'catch' statement?  Or is that what is returned in the onResponse(string response) response variable?  If so, the text 'No value for videoId' is not valid JSON and so, trying to put that into a JSON object would cause a JSONException.  Have you tried using '/youtube.search.list?' instead of just '/search?' ?

Comment: @MichaelDougan , exception message is returned in the catch statement on `e.printStackTrace();` And no, I didn't try to use `'/youtube.search.list?`, do you mean to use it in my url like `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search.list?part=snippet&q=funnyvideos&order=title&maxResults=3&key=(key)`?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think I figured it out. It looks like your response came back OK, and while processing the 'for' loop for each 'item' you are getting the object 'id', and inside of that object, you are looking for the 'videoId'.  Which is fine, for all but the last of the three results, which in your postman results looks like this:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
 "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/sy1iQ191YnpipX54MZQ-Z-bd2YU\"",
 "id": {
  "kind": "youtube#channel",
  "channelId": "UCUd0dDUCXsjBPnG1qeUHZLw"
 },
```

It has a channelId instead of a videoId.  What you should do is trap each JSON expression in it's own try/catch block, so that one bad response does not stop your whole results.  Something like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
JSONObject jsonId = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("id");
String video_id = "";
String channel_id = "";


try {

   video_id = jsonId.getString("videoId");

}catch(JSONException e) {
   channel_id = jsonId.getString("channelId");
}
```

You can try to add more logging and then when you run your code, at least you'll know what is happening by looking at your logs:

```
    public void displayVideos(){
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?" + "part=" + part + "&q=" + keySearch + "&maxResults=3" + "&order=" + order + "&key=" + API_KEY;

        Log.i("My App", "url=" + url);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                Log.i("My App", "response=" + response);

                try{
                    Log.i("My App", "before jsonObject");
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    Log.i("My App", "after jsonObject:" + jsonObject.toString());

                    Log.i("My App", "before jsonArray");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
                    Log.i("My App", "after jsonArray: count=" + jsonArray.length());

                    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                       Log.i("My App", "before jsonObject1");
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                       Log.i("My App", "after jsonObject1:" + jsonObject1.toString());

                        Log.i("My App", "before jsonVideoId");
                        JSONObject jsonVideoId = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("id");
                        Log.i("My App", "after jsonVideoId:" + jsonVideoId.toString());    

...  (your other code here)

                        Log.i("My App", "before videoId");  
                        String video_id = jsonVideoId.getString("videoId");
                        Log.i("My App", "after videoId:" + video_id); 

... (your other code here)   

                    }

                    listView.setAdapter(myadapter);
                    myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch(JSONException e){
                    Log.e("My App", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               Log.e("My App", error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }

}
```

Comment: I tried to use your sequence of code from above, but also nothing happens, and also I tried to modify the part `for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)` in `for(int i=0; i<1; i++)` to obtain just part where videoId exists, but anyway it doesn't works

Comment: But when I tried  `for(int i=0; i<1; i++` I got nothing returned on breakpoint exception, so exception vanished but videos still doesn't show

Comment: I don't recall if it is jsonArray.length() or jsonArray.count() but that is the way to go.  If you say i < 1 you are only ever going to get the first element in the array. I think if you add this to your query string &type=video then you won't get the 'channel' result which you are currently getting in the 3rd result.

Comment: I know that if I'm using i<1 I will get just first element in the array, but i just tried to know if the problem is in parsing till the element with no videoId and seems like not, even the first element with videoId is not showin.

Comment: Tried to use &type=video, nothing happen, still nothing apear when I search, and jsonarray.count doesn't work.

Comment: Are you able to set a breakpoint and step through your onResponse method one instruction at a time?  If you do, you may see that your jsonArray.length() is 0, so, that would tell you one thing.  Or maybe jsonArray is null (meaning it didn't find the 'id' element.  Or maybe jsonObject1 is null etc.  By setting a breakpoint on the first line, then stepping line by line, you can see if each instruction succeeded... and keep going until you find the exact instruction that fails.  That should tell you want to do.

Comment: Ok, I will try, hope it will help.